# Vector Components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

The question states; In the figure below, vector b and c are intersecting faces of a cube of edge a. Find the components of vector d, where d = the vector product of vectors b and c. 
                             [image: Cube Diagram]

With reference to the imagine above. I fist began by describing vectors. Vector b= ai+aj-bk The (a) came from the lenght of the cube. The (-b) from the fact that the vectr has a component in the negative direction z-plane. That is not equal to the lenght of once edge.

```
                          Vector c= -di+aj+ak
```

Vector c was identified with the same assuption as that of B

I used the vectors components to find the vector product that i found to be; bxc = (a^2-ab)-(a^2+bc)+(a^2-ac)

My classmates and I have argued over the questions, and require verification on the method and the answer itself.

Comment: From the figure, it looks like vector B has components (a,a,0) and vector C has components (0,a,a).  Note:  the coordinate frame is right-handed and all vector components are positive or zero.

Comment: Before worrying about vector products, you need to improve your understanding of vector components. Your expressions for the two vectors $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ do not make sense.

Comment: Once you understand how to represent these two vectors... (a^2-ab)-(a^2+bc)+(a^2-ac) does not make sense as their vector product. The vector product produces a *vector*. You have computed a number. And you are failing to distinguish between numbers like $a$ and vectors like $\vec b$ and $\vec c$.

Comment: In short, the method and the answer are both incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Find the components of vector d, where d = the scalar product of vectors b and c.

This makes no sense.  If d is a scalar product of vectors, then it is a scalar, not a vector, so there are no components.

Comment: How are your straight lines defined? For instance, if you have your triangle as the intersection of three half-spaces $\mathbf{N}_i]\cdot\mathbf{p}\geq r_i$ for $i=1\ldots 3$ (i.e., essentially its definition as a 'convex body', then testing if a point is in your triangle is just testing that it liers in all three half-spaces.

Comment: maybe they meant "tensor d"?

Comment: The error was on my part, they asked for the vector product